# Ssh can't resolve host name, but the host command can?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, internal-dns

I'm having some weird issue that I cannot understand (I'm trying to ssh to `alexus` and according to `ssh` it tells me it cannot resolve, yet when i use `host` to resolve it resolves w/out any issues:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ ssh -v alexus
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alexus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname alexus: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
mbp:~ alexus$ host alexus
alexus.XXXXXXXXX.org is an alias for XXX.XXXXXXXXX.org.
XXX.XXXXXXXXX.org has address 10.XX.XXX.XXX
mbp:~ alexus$
```

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Do you have anything in `~/.ssh/config` which might point `alexus` to a different IP for SSH?

Comment: What does `grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf` give you?

Comment: Just in case, in `/etc/resolv.conf` do you have `search XXXXXXXXX.org` ?

Comment: @c4urself : there is nothing in my `~/.ssh/config` that relates to `alexus`. @MadHatter : I don't have `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. @NickW : yes, I do!

Comment: Is alexus a CNAME on all your DNS servers then?

Comment: @NickW: yes, it's a CNAME

Comment: This guy blames it on the glibc resolver.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149540/host-is-able-to-resolve-a-hostname-ssh-isnt

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way that should resolve the issue is to just add the name to /etc/hosts, like this:

`10.XX.XXX.XXX alexus`

Other thoughts:

Does ssh -v alexus.XXXXXXXXX.org work?  Is alexus.XXXXXXXXX.org a name that resolves on the Internet?  If so, does setting up /etc/resolv.conf to use Google's name servers resolve the problem?  e.g.

```
search XXXXXXXXX.org
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Also, what do the name servers say when directly connected?  What does "dig @10.1.2.3 alexus.XXXXXXXXX.org" give you (replace 10.1.2.3 with the actual IP of the DNS server you are using)?  How about "dig @10.1.2.3 alexus.XXXXXXXXX.org AAAA"?

Comment: if hostname is dns resolvable then there is no need to add anything to hosts file..